# How to calculate total power required for an electric vehicle (ebike) design?

Tags: power-electronics, physics, electric-machine, calculus

I wanted to design an ebike with good enough specs to satisfy my requirements, my first consideration was the power required to move the bike at my required speed and from there I can choose a motor.

I started by setting the max speed, max total weight (rider + bike), and acceleration:

- Top speed: 50 km/h, 13.88 m/s
- Maximum weight: 200 kg, 1,974 N
- Acceleration: 0-50 km/h in 30 sec, ~ 0.5 m/s^2

Then what forces to consider:

1. Drag.
2. Friction.
3. Force required to reach the required speed.
4. As the force required to overcome inclination of the ground is regained, I decided to neglect it.

To calculate each one I used rough conditions. Here is how I calculated each one of the forces:

F1:

```
Equation : ( (air density) (wind resistance coefficient) (Area) (wind velocity)^2 ) / 2

1. air density: 1 kg/m^3
2. coefficient: ~ 1
3. Area: ~ 0.5 m^2
4. (wind velocity)^2 : average 15 km/h + max speed = 65 km/h, ~ (18)^2 = 324 m/s

Total = 81 N
```

F2:

```
Equation: (coefficient of rolling resistance) (mg) 
1- coefficient: ~ 0.01
2- mg: 1,974 N

Total = 19.74 N
```

F3:

```
Equation: ma
1- ma : 100 N

Total = 100 N
```

Ftotal = 200.74 N

Ptotal = Ftotal * Velocity = 2,786.27 W, ~ 3.75 HP

Here is where I stalled. I think this power is the power required to move from rest to the required velocity, then the momentum will keep the bike moving and the power it will consume would be the power required to overcome friction and drag, which is around 1.4 kW.

What did I miss and is there a flaw in these calculations?

1400 W to maintain my speed sounds a lot to me.  What does the total power of 2,786 W mean in W per hour and what motor power do all these calculations translate to?

Where does work and K.E. fit into these calculations, if relevant?

P.S. I know that there are inefficiencies in the bike, the motor,and in energy getting lost converting from electrical energy to mechanical energy, but it can be considered later.

Edit 1:

What I meant by "what does 2,786 W mean in W/h"
is if I was choosing a motor do I need
it to be able output 2,786 W of power
or I can divide it as it is a quantity of energy.

Edit 2:

I calculated Kinetic Energy
~ 5 W/h or 20kJ and work with 1 km
displacement to be ~ 56 W/h or 200kj.

Work might be correct as the numbers
seem close to typical ranges, but K.E.
Is really small.

I think my calculations are flawed
because I use constant values
Ie. When I start driving the wind
wouldn't be 65 km/h, but thankfully I
think it can be solved by integration
of wind velocity squared vs time
(not sure yet I will do calculations and post it) .

Also if it had 2,786 W - 1,400 W
of power as momentum, when I brake I
will experience 1,386 W of power
divided by time I take to stop which
if we set to 3 sec as an arbitrary value
I will experience ~ 45 kg
if I braked in a distance of 1 meter
for 3 seconds continuously and that is
if the tire's sliding friction allows for it
(I think, but please correct me if I'm wrong)

I know that W/h is energy, which gets
consumed from the battery, I'm asking
for it because of peak power requirements
as @johnBreakhead commented,
which is the more appropriate term.

P.S. All the inefficienies will be calculated later and I will divide the total power by it to get the final peak power.

Comment: There are lots of calculators that determine the power to cycle at a particular speed. Look in the cycling stack exchange or Google "bicycle performance prediction calculator"

Comment: I searched a couple, they give different answers I want to make a calculator of my own which I can reach a relatively close answer I inputed close values to the above, also I want to be able to calculate it at any condition for different vehicles and I can use the same equations for any type of motor not only electrical, but thanks It will be helpful to compare my values with them.

Comment: I can get 50 kph on a derestricted Bosch 250 W system with leg assistance. Bear in mind that a bike's drive train and wheels will not be rated for more than a human can give (300 - 500 W for very fit rider and typically < 150 W for normal rider). Coming off at 50 kph may result in very serious and permanent injury.

Comment: No such thing as _watt per hour_. Do you mean energy as in watt-hour? Also, your 3 is just the result of 1 and 2.

Comment: Keep in mind regulations around max speed for e bikes. e.g things get complicated above 25kph around here.

Comment: You're on the right track.  To get your power required to move from rest to the required velocity, calculate the kinetic energy at the end velocity and how many seconds you are going to allow to get to the end velocity.  Since KE is in joules and watts are joules/sec, this will tell you how much power it takes to accelerate.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead, I did so and I got 20kj when I divided it by 3,600 I got ~ 5 watt hours which didn't make sense.

Comment: I think this question mostly belongs on the Physics site, if you are looking for a verification of your calculations.

Comment: I posted it there first and it got closed twice due to being off topic and engineering being more appropriate.

Comment: For example, if your answer is 20 kJ, and you wanted to accelerate to this speed in 30 seconds, then your required power is 667 W.  This must be added to your previous value of 2786 W to get your total power requirement.  You are confusing units.  Watt-hours (energy) are a measure of battery capacity, used to determine how long you can go at a certain power level.  So if you are cruising at 2000 watts for an hour, your battery energy is 2000 watt-hours.   Since your peak power is around 3500W, you must choose a battery that can deliver (with a 36V battery you would need to deliver 100 amps).

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helpful, but where does this energy go after I cruse does it subtract from the energy required to overcome friction and drag or does it stay conserved until I break?

Comment: Energy is converted to kinetic E=1/2mv² and is lost faster with heat rise by  thermal resistance Rth* I²R * losses and might be cooled by air. So motor temperature rise is an indicator of energy inefficiency.

Comment: The throttle only controls the avearge motor voltage and max no load RPM or cruising speed with load friction, not the current and thermal losses which can be up to 10x greater from a dead stop if (?) there was no acceleration limit.  So conserve max acceleration wisely.

Comment: I made an EV calculator using JavaScript that was mostly intended for electric car conversions, but I think it should work for a motorized bicycle as well. Give it a try - it might help. http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot @PStechPaul, I used it and the numbers seem close, and thanks a lot Tony Stewart EE75, I know that there are tons of loses, but I can later divide the peak power by the total efficiency of gearing, bike bearings, electrical efficiency of the motor, etc to get the motor required to deliver the required power.

Comment: "*I know that W/h is energy ...*" No! ***Energy = power x time = watts x hours = Wh***. W/h is non-sensical.